# Folder as python String wit \_

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, jira-rest-api

i want to print a foldername as a python 3.9 string.
It looks like

```
C:\ABC\DEF\_GHI
```

When i use

```
print(r'C:\ABC\DEF\_GHI')
```

it works generally. BUT:
I need to print it in Jira as a issue comment. There it unfortunately looks like this:
C:\ABC\DEF_GHI

I use the default JIRA API for python

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jiraConnection = JIRA(basic_auth=(self.username, self.password), options=self.options)
jiraConnection.add_comment(issueID,r'C:\ABC\DEF\_GHI')
```

Result: C:\ABC\DEF_GHI

i did try:

```
r''
Result: C:\ABC\DEF_GHI
'C:\\ABC\\DEF\\_GHI'
Result: 
C:\ABC\DEF
_GHI
'C:\\ABC\\DEF\\\_GHI'
Result: 
C:\ABC\DEF_GHI
```

Comment: a convenient way to handle paths in Python: use the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try double backslashes with `r` prefix:

```
jiraConnection.add_comment(issueID, r'C:\\ABC\\DEF\\_GHI')
```

or forward slashes if double backslashes still not working:

```
jiraConnection.add_comment(issueID, 'C:/ABC/DEF/_GHI')
```

Comment: if you use a raw string literal, you do not have to escape the backslashes

Comment: Forwardslashes did the trick! Thank you. Looks weird af but still works when copied and pasted into windows explorer. the first suggestions did not work, again the \\ was a endline in jira somehow